# Cannot get value of an object in Angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have this `factory` in my AngularJS:

```
app.factory('userFactory', function($window) {
    var auth = {
        isLogged: false,      
        user: "a",
        check: function() {
            if ($window.sessionStorage.token) {
                this.isLogged = true;
            } else {
                this.isLogged = false;
                delete this.user;
            }
        }
    }
    return auth;
});
```

I put this static, for testing, inside an AngularJS `controller`, when a `button` is clicked this runs.

```
// replace "a" with the following
app.controller('LoginCtrl', ['$scope', '$window', '$location', 'userFactory',
    function ($scope, $window, $location, userFactory) {     
        $scope.login = function(){
            var userCredentials = {
                "username": $scope.username,
                "password": $scope.password
            };
            if (userCredentials.username == "amir" && userCredentials.password == "blum") {
                userFactory.isLogged = true;
                userFactory.user = {
                    "name": "amir",
                    "surname": "blumenfeld"
                };
                $location.path("/customer");
            } else {
                alert("NO");
            }
        }
    }
]);
```

And then I try to do:

```
function menuCtrl($scope, $location, userFactory, $window) {
    $scope.user = userFactory.user.surname;
}
```

So "blumenfeld" supposed to rendered here

```
<ul ng-controller="menuCtrl">                
    <li><a href="#home">{{ user }}</a></li>                                                                                                    
</ul>
```

But I get nothing, just an empty space.

Please help me understand where I did wrong. How can I fix this?

Thanks

Comment: plunker? can your share code?

Comment: It's sounds like you have a race condition. As you're changing `$scope.user` the value will not be recomputed when you modify `userFactory.user` in a different controller.

Comment: @LoïcFaure-Lacroix there can't be a race condition. once enough digest cycles are run a value will be present

Comment: @antoniskamamis sure there is a race condition, the value `surname` doesn't exists when set to the scope but later when button is clicked.

Comment: @VasiliyVanchuk I added more info. Take a look

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you seems to be setting `$scope.user` to `userFactory.user.surname` when it's created. In other words, your `user` is `a` and `surname` is `undefined`.

Then in your click event, you're setting `userFactory.user` to an object. But as the `$scope.user` is set to undefined, it has no way to know that it's value depends on the `userFactory.user` and the value isn't changed and will always be `undefined`.

If you want something that works, you'll have to set the object in your factory to an object. And in your click event, you'll have to update the values without changing the object.

```js
var app = angular.module('MyApp', []);
app.factory('userFactory', function($window) {
    var auth = {
      isLogged: false,      
      user: {
         name: "a",
         surname: "a",
         job: "a",
      }
    }
    return auth;
  });

app.controller('menuCtrl2', ['$scope', 'userFactory', function($scope, userFactory){
  $scope.load = function () {
    userFactory.user.name = "amir"
    userFactory.user.surname = "blumenfeld"
    userFactory.user.job = "crazy" 
  }
}]);

app.controller('menuCtrl', ['$scope', 'userFactory', function($scope, userFactory){
  $scope.user = userFactory.user;
}]);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div class="container" ng-app="MyApp">
  <div ng-controller="menuCtrl2">
     <button ng-click="load()">Load</button>
  </div>
  <div class="row" ng-controller="menuCtrl">
    {{user.surname}}
  </div>
</div>
```

Here's a second version using a method:

```js
var app = angular.module('MyApp', []);
app.factory('userFactory', function($window) {
    var auth = {
      isLogged: false,      
      user: {
         name: "a",
         surname: "a",
         job: "a",
      }
    }
    return auth;
  });

app.controller('menuCtrl2', ['$scope', 'userFactory', function($scope, userFactory){
  $scope.load = function () {
    userFactory.user = {"name":"amir", "surname":"blumenfeld", "job":"crazy"};
  }
}]);

app.controller('menuCtrl', ['$scope', 'userFactory', function($scope, userFactory){
  $scope.user = function () {
    return userFactory.user.surname
  }
}]);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div class="container" ng-app="MyApp">
  <div ng-controller="menuCtrl2">
     <button ng-click="load()">Load</button>
  </div>
  <div class="row" ng-controller="menuCtrl">
    {{user()}}
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I will check and let you know. I added more info in my original post. Check it out if you like

Comment: note that the template can't use simply "user" as it's a basic value that cannot be guessed if changed unless changed explicitly in the scope.

Comment: This is still not working for some reason. I will check again and and let you know.

Answer (score 0):

I copy pasted your code and it seems working [look here](http://jsfiddle.net/yvbenitah/zjFp4/812/)

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);
myApp.factory('userFactory', function($window) {
    var auth = {
      isLogged: false,      
      user: "a"
    }
    return auth;
  });
function MyCtrl($scope, userFactory) {
    userFactory.user = {"name":"amir","surname":"blumenfeld","job":"crazy"};
     $scope.user = userFactory.user.surname; 
}
```

Comment: Same thing here, userFactory.user is set after $scope.user is set.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to update my fiddle. @slevin is working now

Answer (score -2):

Try to create user object without "" around properties names:

```
userFactory.user = {name:"amir",surname:"blumenfeld",job:"crazy"};
```